# Spoon screenshots not visible in log from Android 6.0+ device

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, spoon, android-instrumentation

People who write integration tests for sure have heard about Spoon and Spoon-Gradle-Plugin which provide useful functions for your tests. I am using [stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin).

I am using screenshot method provided by class `com.squareup.spoon.Spoon.java` in my tests. After I run my tests by `"./gradlew spoon"` command, it generates for me xml file with logs and screenshots from each tests. This works for each android device with system version below 6.0. When I run tests on device with Marshmallow my console looks like this at the end of the tests:

```
2015-12-18 15:58:00 [STRL.testRunEnded] elapsedTime=408847
03:58:00 I/XmlResultReporter: XML test result file generated at /Users/F1sherKK/Dev/myapp-Android/app/build/spoon-log/normal/debugRelease/junit-reports/05f3785c3444f1bf.xml. Total tests 32, failure 1, passed 31, 
2015-12-18 15:58:00 [SDR.run] About to grab screenshots and prepare output for [05f3785c3444f1bf]
2015-12-18 15:58:00 [SDR.pullDirectory] Internal path is /data/data/com.myapp.sendmoney.debug1/app_spoon-screenshots
2015-12-18 15:58:00 [SDR.pullDirectory] External path is /sdcard/app_spoon-screenshots
2015-12-18 15:58:00 [SDR.pullDirectory] Pulling files from external dir on [05f3785c3444f1bf]
2015-12-18 15:58:05 [SDR.pullDirectory] Pulling files from internal dir on [05f3785c3444f1bf]
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.pullDirectory] Done pulling app_spoon-screenshots from on [05f3785c3444f1bf]
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.pullDirectory] Internal path is /data/data/com.myapp.sendmoney.debug1/app_spoon-files
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.pullDirectory] External path is /sdcard/app_spoon-files
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.pullDirectory] Pulling files from external dir on [05f3785c3444f1bf]
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.pullDirectory] Pulling files from internal dir on [05f3785c3444f1bf]
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.pullDirectory] Done pulling app_spoon-files from on [05f3785c3444f1bf]
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Moving screenshots to the image folder on [05f3785c3444f1bf]
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.flowtests.NotificationCenterActivity.NotificationCenterActivityFunctionTest#assertReferralPopUpWillAppear
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.flowtests.NotificationCenterActivity.NotificationCenterActivityFunctionTest#assertReferralPopUpWillHide
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#addMockItem_newMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#clickOnBackButton_returnToNotificationCenter
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#clickOnBackButton_returnToNotificationCenter
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#clickOnBackButton_returnToNotificationCenter
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#clickOnBackButton_returnToNotificationCenter
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.CustomerServiceActivity.CustomerServiceNavigator#clickOnItem_referralType
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.General.GeneralNavigator#sendNotification_addSampleMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.General.GeneralNavigator#sendNotification_addSampleMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.General.GeneralNavigator#sendNotification_addSampleMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.General.GeneralNavigator#sendNotification_addSampleMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.General.GeneralNavigator#sendNotification_addSampleMessage
2015-12-18 15:58:06 [SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.myapp.sendmoney.instrumentation.navigation.activity.InviteFriendsActivity.InviteFriendsNavigator#clickOnBackButton_returnToCustomerService
```

So first thing that comes to my mind when I see this is... problem with permission handling that changed since android 6.0. So I thought if I provide

> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

and

> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

permissions to my app it should work. So I created this simple shell script that detects SDK version and if it's equal or higher to 23 then grants permissions to my package before test start.

```
SDK=`adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk | tr -d '\r'`

if (( "$SDK" >= 23 )) ; then

    adb shell pm grant com.myapp.sendmoney.debug1 android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

    adb shell pm grant com.myapp.sendmoney.debug1 android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

fi
./gradlew spoon
```

Seems like my permissions are granted but after test start I still cannot pull screenshots from the device.

My second thought is then. Okay if thats not a problem with permissions, then maybe there are no screenshots to be pulled. So Spoon cleans screenshots from your device after tests finish. I started tests, waited till some of them will finish and then killed process in my console ctrl+C. I opened Android Device Monitor and I could see that screenshots from my tests are there waiting for pull. Still it doesn't happen.

So my third thought was. Okay if thats not with permissions and screenshot function works fine on 6.0 device, then maybe it's a spoon problem. I tried to look for similar topics online but none of them was directly related to my case.

I found [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195927&q=label%3AType-Defect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), but it didn't solve my problem. I'm not using `UIAutomator` to take screenshot but Spoon's screenshot method.

[There is](https://github.com/square/spoon/issues/292) a problem I am fighting with now I guess, but I did the suggested thing and it didn't help.

And [there](https://github.com/square/spoon/issues/293) was some fix 4 days ago, but I am still facing problem now and my libs are recent ones:

```
dependencies {

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jraska:falcon-spoon-compat:0.3.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }

    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2"
}
```

and

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'

        (...)

        classpath 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-runner:1.2.1'
        classpath ('com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT') {
            exclude module: "guava"
        }
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    }
```

So... maybe I am missing something. Maybe there is another permission needed I forgot about. I am grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: The gradle plugin does not use the latest version of spoon where the issue is fixed.

https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin/pull/91

Comment: i think there's still problems with permissions you're adding that (in your script) like it was Kitkat device or older. Permissions in Lollipop changed, so you need to check if you don't need more additional code.

Comment: Please add this as issue on Github pages (Spoon and spoon-gradle-plugin). I haven't already used spoon - Gradle reports are for me enough. but why don't you learn some more about `uiatomator`, which is provided and supported by  Google? I think with it's help you may avoid problem like this

Comment: For a number a of reasons I do not run tests with spoon on Android 6. Hence, cannot validate whether it works. But here's an issue in Spoon project tracking this problem: https://github.com/square/spoon/issues/313